# Examples of relatively complex truth tables/logic gates in real life?

Tags: circuits, boolean-algebra

I'm researching truth tables, logical gates, and boolean algebra expressions. I'm trying to find specific real-life examples of logic gates and/or truth tables used in algorithm or circuit design in the real world. I've found things such as the adder circuit, but I was wondering if there were any logic puzzles or algorithms found in well-known programs (video games, for example) that could be represented by truth tables, or if you simply any more logic gates in a well-known piece of circuitry or hardware? I think it would be really cool to go and analyze practical examples in particular. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Real-life circuits have a different model of computation, in which there is memory and computation can proceed in several rounds.